# SP2013 and MVC 5: How do I add user information?

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I was tasked in making an Intranet for our company. I have no training whatsoever in SharePoint so I'm having a hard time. We're also using Active Directory.

First question, is SP2013 MVC using something similar to MVC5's UserIdentity?

I also have this MVC template where it's using SharePointContextProvider, which I thought was similar to UserIdentity. However, I can't really extend it since it doesn't have any Model class yet.

```
[SharePointContextFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        User spUser = null;

        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                spUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;

                clientContext.Load(spUser, user => user.Title);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                ViewBag.UserName = spUser.Title;
            }
        }

        return View(); 
    }
```

Was hoping if I could add more information for that spUser. Like for example, having their address, contact number and etc.

Is there anyway of doing this properly?

What I'm thinking of is just getting the spUser.Email from the context provider and make a method that counter checks that email to a new table I'm going to create which has all the employee information. So if spUser.Email = newTable.Email then this checks out and I list all their info on their profile page.

Answer (score 0):

If  you're building a SharePoint 2013 intranet, you should be getting this information from the User Profile. check out the following post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163182.aspx